# How can I get redis io client from NestJS CacheManager module

Tags: nestjs, node-redis, cachemanager

I am currently using cache manager module from NestJS and I was wondering why I can't get the NodeRedis client like this :

```
 constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
  ) {
    cacheManager.store.getClient();
  }
```

I am getting this error :

```
ERROR in [...].controller.ts:24:24
TS2339: Property 'getClient' does not exist on type 'Store'.
    22 |     @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
    23 |   ) {
  > 24 |     cacheManager.store.getClient();
       |                        ^^^^^^^^^
    25 |   }
```

I did configured the cache-manager-redis-store when I registered the CacheModule then I supposed I could get the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr It seems that `cache-manager-redis-store` isn't properly supported by TypeScript because the `RedisCache` type is private and can't be imported.

As a workaround, you could copy the private types to your own file:

```js
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Store } from 'cache-manager';
import Redis from 'redis';

interface RedisCache extends Cache {
  store: RedisStore;
}

interface RedisStore extends Store {
  name: 'redis';
  getClient: () => Redis.RedisClient;
  isCacheableValue: (value: any) => boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CacheService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)
    private cacheManager: RedisCache,
  ) {
    cacheManager.store.getClient();
  }
}
```

#### Deep Dive

It looks like the `CACHE_MANAGER` provided by NestJS is created by [createCacheManager](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/cache/cache.providers.ts), which imports the npm package `cache-manager` and then invokes its `caching` function with the store package you give.

I think the `Cache` type you're using is imported from `cache-manager`. The type is defined [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cache-manager/index.d.ts#L55) and contains a `Store` contained [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cache-manager/index.d.ts#L17) in the same file. `getClient` is not a method method on that interface, so the error message is correct.

However, since you're using an external package for the store, there's more to it than `caching-manager` knows about. Looking at the types for `cache-manager-redis-store`, you can see there's a type [RedisStore](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cache-manager-redis-store/index.d.ts#L22) that extends `Store` and includes `getClient`.

So `cacheManager` technically has `getClient` since you've configured it with the redis store package, but you need to set the type on your `cacheManager` variable to `RedisCache` for TypeScript to allow it.

Based on the DefinitelyTyped types for `cache-manager-redis-store`, it seems your type should be `redisStore.CacheManagerRedisStore.RedisCache` if you imported the package as `redisStore`, but there seems to be an issue because that namespace `CacheManagerRedisStore` is not exported.

There's [an issue about this same problem](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/issues/14) on the repo and [there's an issue asking for TypeScript support](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/issues/20). It seems this package isn't properly supported by TypeScript at this time.

Comment: i got error cacheManager.store.getClient is not a function

Comment: So do I, do you have any progress with that?

Comment: In my case, with the `cache-manager-redis-yet` package, I did: `(app.get(CACHE_MANAGER) as RedisCache).store.client`.

`RedisCache` is imported from the same package.